# PHP tables' and titles' positions askew

Tags: php, html

This outline of php code I'm writing shows a combination of 3 tables, and table names. When shown one at a time the title is above the table, but when all three are shown, the text within the  tags pile up above the tables. Any idea how to get around this??

```
<?php

if($_GET["pokemon"] == 'P')
     {
     #query to find pokemon cards in a deck
     <h2>Pokemon</h2>
     <table> #print a table based on query
     }

if($_GET["trainer"] == 'T')
     {
     #query to find trainer cards in a deck
     <h2>Trainers</h2>
     <table> #print a table based on query
     }

if($_GET["energies"] == 'E')
     {
     #query to find energy cards in a deck
     <h2>Energies</h2>
     <table> #print a table based on query
     }

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the text within the tags pile up'? Please add a screenshot.

Comment: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~bainro/test3.php?pname=emily&pokemon=P&trainer=T&energy=E

You can ignore the button. I'll tackle that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are closing your `<table></table>` tags

the same goes for your other tags:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That was it! Thx! It's interesting that it still worked and did what it did.

Comment: That is because of the implementation browsers have of standards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close all open tags..

imho, you are opening three table tags and may be closing only once..

Also, add more code to your post..